# sed unknown option to s error

Tags: linux, bash, sed, makefile

I have a Makefile which has a line:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(^COPTS = \)/\1$(CFLAGS) /' $(DIR)/Makefile
```

After substituting values it becomes:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(^COPTS = \)/\1"-I/home/jagadeesh/Smoothwall/bcutm/distrib/tools//powerpc-linux/include -I/home/jagadeesh/Smoothwall/bcutm/distrib/usr/include/ncurses -I/home/jagadeesh/Smoothwall/bcutm/distrib/usr/include" /' net-tools-1.60/Makefile
```

When make is run it gives following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unknown option to `s'
```

The net-tool-1.60/Makefile on which this sed command is going to run contains following relevant lines:

```
COPTS = -D_GNU_SOURCE -O2 -Wall -g # -I/usr/inet6/include
CFLAGS  = $(COPTS) -I. -idirafter ./include/ -I$(NET_LIB_PATH)
MDEFINES = COPTS='$(COPTS)' LOPTS='$(LOPTS)' TOPDIR='$(TOPDIR)'
```

What does that command do, to which line of the Makefile, why is the error comming, I didn't modify anything except CFLAGS and LDFLAGS which are my custom.

Answer (score 2):

Since the replacement part contains the delimiter `/`, the command fails. I suggest to use a different delimiter, let's say `~`:

```
sed -i -e 's~\(^COPTS = \)~\1$(CFLAGS) ~' $(DIR)/Makefile
```